# rewriterule for multiple 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried looking my question up, but the closest answers I've found didn't work--especially since I'm VERY new to editing `.htaccess` files.

I have a site that has been programmed to dynamically generate copies of a page to fit a location. For instance, `example.com/help/work/` was set up to make about 100 duplicates that look like this: `example.com/help/work/?city=Washington&state=DC` with the city and state dynamically changing with each page.There are tons of these variations and I want to 301 redirect all the pages with a city and state parameter so they point to the original page (`example.com/help/work/`).

After some research, I was able to find a RewriteRule that helped me do this on a page by page basis, but only with the homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=Philadelphia&state=PA$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

With all that said, I have a two part question:

1. Is there a way to write this so that it targets subdirectory pages? (I could only get it to do the index)
2. Is there a way I can use a wildcard like (.*) in a single RewriteRule so `example.com/help/work/?city=Washington&state=DC` and all its city/state variations point to the original page (`example.com/help/work/`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on your request. It appears you want to point every city and state to this single page. `http://example.com/help/work/` See if this is what you're looking for.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} city=.+&state=.+
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/$1/$2/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify a little bit, here's a better example of what I'm trying to do:

Right now I have pages like example.com, example.com/idea/good/ and example.com/help/work. These are the original, canonical pages I want everyone to see. 

There are also pages being generated that copy those pages and adds the "city/state" parameter. So each of the url examples I listed about has about 100 variations dynamically created url. I'm trying to make it so all the city/state pages redirect to their respective canonical page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just to give additional insight, this is another one I've been trying. Am I on the right track? 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=.*&state=.*$
RewriteRule ^help/work/$ http://example.com/help/work/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer as to what I think you tried to clarify. Please see if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner--east coast snow storm! But I wanted to say thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok no problem. Please accept the answer by clicking the check box

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use a  regex capture group in Rewrite rule that  captures the request_uri dynmically .

Like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=.+&state=.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```